# Dealing with knockout radio lookups effectively

Tags: knockout.js

ith my view I am binding to an ID (in my case an SKU) on the view-model, I have a computed value which performs look-ups as below (**[fiddle link here](http://jsfiddle.net/g18c/2SAxR/3/)**):

**View**

```
<div data-bind="foreach: server">
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="server" data-bind="attr: {value: sku}, checked: $root.selectedServer" />
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<p data-bind="text: selectedServer"></p>
<p data-bind="text: description"></p>
```

**View-Model**

```
var serverOptions = [{
    name: "One",
    sku: 1000,
    specification: "yes",
    price: 100
}, {
    name: "Two",
    sku: 1001,
    specification: "hello",
    price: 200
}, {
    name: "Three",
    sku: 1002,
    specification: "wow",
    price: 300
}];

viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.server = serverOptions;
    self.selectedServer = ko.observable();

    self.description = ko.computed(function () {
        var selectedSku = this.selectedServer();

        // needs to be checked as on viewmodel creation the computed function will be called
        // and selectedServer will not be selected
        if(typeof selectedSku == "undefined")
            return;

        var found = ko.utils.arrayFirst(serverOptions, function (item) {
            return item.sku == selectedSku;
        }, this);

        var textDescription = found.name + " - " + found.specification + " (" + found.price + ")";

        return textDescription;
    }, this);

    return self;
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

I will have quite a number of these lookups from radio button selections, and as can be seen as far as I understand error checking needs to be performed on each as initially the radio button on which the computed value depends will be undefined on view-model creation - this makes the view-model code quite 'bulky'.

Is the above code the most effective way, can computed binding triggers be postponed till the viewmodel is built, or are there any other knockout utility functions (or re-factoring) which could make the view-model cleaner?

My javascript skills are still slowly coming together as a crash course from years of C# its quite different, so appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Did you try `subscribe`? It's like `ko.computed` but it will not fire until the viewModel is initialized. It's described at the bottom of [this page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html). Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delay the evaluation of a computed, add deferEvaluation option.

```
self.description = ko.computed({
        read : function () {
        var selectedSku = this.selectedServer();

        [...]

        return textDescription;

      },
      deferEvaluation : true,

}, this);
```

See [compted documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) about deferEvaluation.